# Loop Through List of Files in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have a list of files that I get by executing this: `ls core_* | sort -n -t _ -k 2`

which gives me something like this:

`core_20171201142359.csv
core_20171202131548.csv
core_20171203141112.csv`

The objective is to get a single file in which to append all the content of every single file in order.

So, I want to open every single file one by one, copy its content into another file, move the previous source file to another directory for safekeeping and move on.

To always get the very first file in order I use `ls core_* | sort -n -t _ -k 2 | head -1`, and I need to cycle all of those files.

How can I know when there are no more files that I need to process?

Comment: @Cyrus it will write the names of the files in to the new_file instead of each file content, isn't it?

Comment: @ViktorKhilin: Good catch.

Comment: correct me if am wrong, the date format already ensures correct order you need... `cat core_* >> single_file.csv` should do the trick... to move the files, `mv core_* /bkp/path`

Comment: Sundeep is correct. If you need to iterate explicitly, `for file in core_*; ...` -- [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for file in $(ls core_* | sort -n -t _ -k 2)
do
    cat ${file} >> one_big_file.csv
    mv ${file} /anywhere/you/want
done
```

Will read each file, copy all lines into one_big_file.csv, remove just read file to the /anywhere/you/want

Comment: Thank you very much! For the little I know about bash, I think your answer allows me to implement logging.

Comment: About the pitfalls of using `ls`in a `for`read this http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: [quote your variables with quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667) -> `cat "$file"...`, `mv "$file" ...`

Answer (score 2):

For bash, you can store the filenames in an array:

```
files=(core_*)
```

Then the first entry is

```
first="${files[0]}"
```

And you can iterate with this (the quotes are absolutely required)

```
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Or, if you need to do something with all the files at once:

```
cat "${files[@]}" > core_all.csv
```

but if that's the case, you don't need to store them at all

```
cat core_* > core_all.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
ls core_* | sort -n -t _ -k 2 | while read f; do cat $f >> total.csv; done
```

Also alongside with `cat` you can perform `move` etc.